# NAnt fails with "Invalid element <checksum>. Unknown task or datatype"

Tags: nant, nantcontrib

I had to move from `nant-0.86` to `nant-0.92`

This part of the code now fails with: `Invalid element <checksum>. Unknown task or datatype.`

```
<target name="make_one_cksum">
   <!--  <echo message="ECHO za md5 ${filename}" /> -->
   <checksum algorithm="MD5" fileext="MD5_nov">
      <fileset>
         <include name="${filename}"/>
      </fileset>
   </checksum>
</target>
```

Any suggestions to make this work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to update your NAnt.Contrib.Task to 0.93.

**Requirements
Assembly: NAnt.Contrib.Tasks (0.93.5041.0)**

http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/nightly/latest/help/tasks/checksum.html